# What is the general form of an area-preserving map of $\mathbb{R}_2$?

Tags: geometry, symplectic-geometry

A Hamiltonian flow generates such a map. But what is the most general form of such a map? Any theorem? Any procedure to generate such a map?

Of course, I want the map to be continuous.

Comment: In two dimensions, area-preserving = symplectic. So you can construct such maps using the machinery of generating functions (as described in many mechanics textbooks).

Answer (score 2):

If you consider continuously differentiable maps, then by the integration by substitution formula we have that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is (locally) volume preserving if and only if the equality$$\det(df_x)=\pm1$$holds for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: But this is not what I want. This is still superficial.